# Trigger an event with ApplicationEventPublisher from a RabbitMQ listener class

Tags: java, spring-rabbit

In a webapp (Java 8, Spring 4) I have a Rabbit listener class, and I need to trigger an event when the handler method finish its execution.

When I put this code inside the listener class a NullPointerException is thrown, but if I put it in a @Controller or a @Service running in the "main" thread everything works fine. I believe that it something with the context or something like that.

```
public class MyListener {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;
    ...

    private void sendNotification() {
        ...
        publisher.publishEvent(notificationEvent);
    }
}
```

"publisher" object is not null and "notificationEvent" is not null, (it is not a basic error).

I was debugging into spring-context.jar sources, and exception is thrown inside a reflection class called "Method",

```
// java.lang.reflect.Method, line 483
return ma.invoke(obj, args);
```

As I said if i put this code in a Controller or Service running in the "main thread" everything is ok, but when I put it in a Rabbit class Listener I get this error.

```
<bean id="myListener" class="com.example.MyListener />

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" error-handler="queueErrorHandler" >
    <rabbit:listener ref="myListener" method="handleMethod" queue-names="myQueue" />        
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

I believe that is something with the execution context, but I don't know what can be

Comment: Do you have `<context:annotation-config />` or `<context:component-scan />` in that xml file? If not the annotations will simply be ignored.

Comment: Yes. All beans are successfully created.

Comment: The fact that beans get created successfully doesn't mean you have either of those. It just looks like you don't have either of those in your context. Just amuse yourself and add `<context:annotation-config />`. Basically an `@Autowired` field in spring wil never be null, either you are creating new instances yourself or you haven't setup annotation processing. If you have everything setup correctly the application wouldn't even start because the dependencies couldn't be satisfied.

Comment: Thanks, but both <context:annotation-config /> and <context:component-scan /> exists in my xml. As I said, the same code in a class executing in the request thread works fine... I think there is something with the rabbit listener (consumer) execution scope..

Comment: Again I highly doubt it. If that would be the case your application would blow up at startup due to the fact the `@Autowired` field couldn't be satisfied.

Comment: Again: I don't doubt it. I'm not blind, my friend. I am seeing it, and you don't.

Comment: The application is starting, I never said the application is not starting up.

Comment: The fact that it starts is the indication your setup is wrong. If you would have a correct setup the `@Autowired` wouldn't be null as it would blow up. As stated an `@Autowired` field cannot be null (unless `required=false` is set). Also if you have the earlier said config add more configuration and information to your post. Currently there is too little information (and with that information it simply cannot be null),

Comment: Also add the **full** `MyHandler` class. What you added doesn't match what you have in your XML configuration.